Keep passed slots to a slotted component via a functional wrapper
Playground
I have the following:
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Input from './Input.js'
import Text from './Text.vue'

const msg = ref('Hello World!')
</script>

<template>
  <Input label="Message">
    <Text v-model="msg">
      <template #icon>❤️</template>
    </Text>
  </Input>
</template>

Input.js:
import {h} from 'vue';
export default function Input({label}, {slots}){
  return slots.default().map(vnode => h(vnode, {}, {label: () => label}))
};

Text.vue:
<script setup>
const model = defineModel();
</script>

<template>
  <div :class="{iconed: $slots.icon}">
    <div v-if="$slots.label"><slot name="label"/></div>
    <span v-if="$slots.icon" class="icon"><slot name="icon"/></span>
    <input v-model="model"/>
  </div>
</template>

Any way keep the icon slot for Text?
I know that I can put the slot into Input and forward it the Text but I would rather keep it like in the template to state explicitly that the slot belongs to Text.

h(vnode) is a reliable but not documented alternative to cloneVNode which merges props but not children.
{ label: ... } overrides VNode's children, this needs to be additionally taken care of:
return slots.default().map(vnode => {
  const children = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(vnode.children || {})
      .filter(([name]) => !name.includes('_'))
  );

  return h(vnode, {}, { ...children, label: () => label });
});

Not filtering out internal underscored properties from children may result in bugs.

it looks ok, but the label slot isn't rendered for some reason

What should "Message" string be rendered to? Text node?

nope, it will be a complex markup

I updated, a problem with non-normalized slots like label could appear
